# Heroku deployment crash rails server syntax error File.expand_path("../spring", __FILE__)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, spring-gem

When deploying on Heroku, the server crashes with this information 
rails server syntax error File.expand_path("../spring", **FILE**)
though everything is working when working locally.
Here is my rail file

```
begin
  load File.expand_path("../spring", __FILE__)
rescue LoadError
end
APP_PATH=File.expand_path('../../config/application', __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

Do you have any idea of the issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution after 1/2 day of struggling You need the following line at the top of the rail file: #!/usr/bin/env ruby 
Surprisingly, it wasn't a problem locally but when deploying on Heroku it was.

Comment: Thank you. That was obnoxious as hell. Got the simplecov gem and placed some lines above the line you mention above. Moving `#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe` back to the top made everything work out.